# Can a deactivated iPhone be used for app development/testing?

Tags: iphone

I'm thinking of upgrading my iPhone 3G and was wondering if I can continue to use it for appstore application development & testing after I do so. I don't want to continue to pay for an additional line and data plan, and I wouldn't be interested in using is as a phone. Would I be able to provision and debug on it? Would it have to be jailbroken?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You definitely can. I'm currently using my deactivated 2G for development. Aside from the 100 Ad-Hoc devices you can test on, you are also allowed to provision a number of phones that you can build directly to, and it doesn't matter if they are deactivated.

Answer (score 0):

as I think, your phone would function the same as iPod Touch (plus Camera). And since you can use iPod Touch for development, so you can also use your deactivated iPhone.